# Define numeric variables

Tags: macros, packages

I would like to define some variables in a tex document. For example, I write in `.tex` something similar as: `Our tool succeeds to validate x samples by Method A, and y samples by Method B. Thus its score is z`. Where `z` is defined as `x+y`, and `x` (resp. `y`) is instanced somewhere else by a number, eg., `30` (resp. `50`). As a result, after the compilation the text turns out to be `Our tool succeeds to validate 30 samples by Method A, and 50 samples by Method B. Thus its score is 80`.

The advantage of this, is that I just need to change the value of some variables, to change all the numbers in the text...

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Your example doesn't need any arithmetic, just `\newcommand\x{80} ... \x     score is \x\%` if you need arithmetic does it just need integers or floating point values (quite different answers in those cases)

Comment: Well, I made the OP a little bit more complicated...

Comment: You didn't answer the question about whether you need floating point values. \the\numexpr 5 / 6\relax divides 5 by 6 returning an _integer_ but TeX doesn't have floating point values so if you need non integer values you'd need to use lengths \the\dimexpr 5pt /6 \relax and then remove the pt (or use a package that does that)

Comment: OK, I don't need the floating point values...

Comment: I just amended the OP...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\x{30}
\newcommand\y{50}
\begin{document}

 I would like to define some variables in a tex document. For example,
 I write in .tex something similar as: Our tool succeeds to validate \x\
 samples by Method A, and \y\ samples by Method B. Thus its score is
 \the\numexpr\x+\y\relax. 

\end{document}
```

output-

[image]

Comment: Thank you... I see how you define `x` and `y`, and what if I still want to define a newcommand `z` which is `x+y`? How to write this definition?

Comment: @SoftTimur \newcommand\myadd[2]{\the\numexpr(#1)+(#2)\relax}} ... \myadd\x\y

Comment: That works... just another question: how much space does the second \ of \x\ add after a number? is it exactly equivalent to a normal space after a number?

Comment: @SoftTimur yes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle why does this not support in [pgf-umlcd](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgf-umlcd/pgf-umlcd-manual.pdf)? I try - `\begin[text width = \x\ cm]{interface}{\x\, \y\}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this works when I use `\x{}` instead of `\x` or \x\

Comment: `\x{}` not work for value greater than 9 or less than -9.` \x` supports for all yet.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I try `\fontsize{17}{\the\numexpr\x*1.2\relax}` but not work. ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

Comment: @alhelal numexr are __integer_ expressions like latex counters you can not multiply by 1.2 (or even store the value of the result )

Comment: How to perform a modulo using this syntax?

Comment: Does it work for negative numbers? Eg.if $x= 30$, $y = -50$, then $z$ will print $-20$?

Comment: @somenxavier you could have tried it in less tine than it took to ask:-) yes why wouldn't it work?

Answer (score 14):

You can use `expl3` features, in particular the `xfp` package, which features `\fpeval` and `\inteval`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand\x{30}
\newcommand\y{50}

\begin{document}

I would like to define some variables in a \TeX{} document. For example,
I write in \texttt{.tex} something similar as: Our tool succeeds to
validate \inteval{\x} samples by Method~A, and \inteval{\y} samples by
Method~B. Thus its score is \inteval{\x+\y}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you could also use `\x{}` instead of `\inteval{\x}`, but with the `\inteval` method you can also do

```
\newcommand{\z}{\x+3*\y}
```

and use `\inteval{\z}`.

This assumes operations on integer; if you need floating point, you can use `\fpeval` instead of `\inteval` (but things get more complex).

Comment: With a current LaTeX release (after 2020-10-01), there's no need to load `xfp`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use counters for this:

```latex
\newcounter{x}
\setcounter{x}{30}
\newcounter{y}
\setcounter{y}{50}
Our tool succeeds to validate \arabic{x} samples by Method A,
and \arabic{y} samples by Method B. Thus its score is 
\the\numexpr\value{x}+\value{y}.
```

Comment: nice solution but doesn't allow for floating point vars.